# Phrase Interpretation 一生会えない気がする。。。

Tags: translation

> もし俺がここで諦めたら、一生会えない気がする

If I give up here, I don't think I'll never see him again.

If I give up here, I feel that I'll  never ever ( in my whole life ) see him again.

My question is simple, what would be the best "translation" or interpretation to this sentence ?

Comment: Well, the "best translation" would be very much a matter of opinion. What part of the sentence worries you? Given your two example translations I thought it might be the 一生 part, but your question title suggests otherwise. Can you please add some more clarity on what you would like to see in an answer?

Comment: It is exactly this 一生 , I would like to know what nuance it adds to the phrase